# Mocking SDK client which has chained methods

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, moq, microsoft-graph-sdks

I need to unit test *Test1()* as below and have to mock [msgraph-sdk](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) create event which has http call.
I was mocking *Request()* and *AddAsync( )* methods but got null value on Act.
What is the correct way to unit test *CreateAsync* by mocking ?

```
public interface IApiClient
{
    Task<Event> CreateAsync(EventItem eventItem);
}

public class ApiClient : IApiClient
{
    private readonly IGraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;


    public ApiClient(IGraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
    {
        _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    }

    public async Task<Event> CreateAsync(EventItem eventItem)
    {
        var item = new Event
        {
            Subject = eventItem.Subject
        };
        return await _graphServiceClient.Users[eventItem.UserInfo.Id].Events
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(item);
    }

}

public class ApiClientTest
{
    private Mock<IGraphServiceClient> _graphServiceClientMock;
    private IApiClient _apiClient;
    private Mock<IUserEventsCollectionRequest> _mockUserEventsCollectionRequest;
    private EventItem _eventItem;

    [SetUp]
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SetupAsync()
    {
        var x = new Microsoft.Graph.Event()
        {
            Subject = "123"
        };

        _graphServiceClientMock = new Mock<IGraphServiceClient>();
        _mockUserEventsCollectionRequest = new Mock<IUserEventsCollectionRequest>();
        _apiClient = new IApiClient(_graphServiceClientMock.Object);

        _graphServiceClientMock.Setup(g => g.Users[_eventItem.UserInfo.Id].Events
                               .Request())
                               .Returns(
        _mockUserEventsCollectionRequest.Setup(g => g.AddAsync(x))
                               .ReturnsAsync(new Event { Id = "asaasaS" });

    }

    [Test]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        // Act
        var newEvent = await _apiClient.CreateAsync(_eventItem);
        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(newEvent);
        Assert.AreEqual("asaasaS", newEvent.Id);
    }
}
```

I was mocking *Request()* and *AddAsync( )* methods but got null value on Act.
What is the correct way to unit test *CreateAsync* by mocking ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of mocking for you to test this, so maybe you should ask yourself is it worth it. If the answer is yes, then here is an example, how you can do that (I put everything into `Test1` method and skipped `[SetUp]` method for better visibility).

```cs
public class ApiClientTest
{
    [Test]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        // Arrange
        Event @event = new Event { Subject = "Subject", Id = "123" };
        EventItem eventItem = new EventItem { Subject = @event.Subject, UserInfo = new UserInfo { Id = @event.Id } };

        Mock<IUserEventsCollectionRequest> mockUserEventsCollectionRequest = new Mock<IUserEventsCollectionRequest>();
        mockUserEventsCollectionRequest.Setup(x => x.AddAsync(It.IsAny<Event>())).ReturnsAsync(@event);

        Mock<IUserEventsCollectionRequestBuilder> mockUserEventsCollectionRequestBuilder = new Mock<IUserEventsCollectionRequestBuilder>();
        mockUserEventsCollectionRequestBuilder.Setup(x => x.Request()).Returns(mockUserEventsCollectionRequest.Object);

        Mock<IUserRequestBuilder> userRequestBuilder = new Mock<IUserRequestBuilder>();
        userRequestBuilder.Setup(x => x.Events).Returns(mockUserEventsCollectionRequestBuilder.Object);

        Mock<IGraphServiceClient> graphServiceClient = new Mock<IGraphServiceClient>();
        graphServiceClient.Setup(x => x.Users[It.IsAny<string>()]).Returns(userRequestBuilder.Object);

        IApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(graphServiceClient.Object);

        // Act
        Event newEvent = await apiClient.CreateAsync(eventItem);

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(newEvent);
        Assert.AreEqual(@event.Id, newEvent.Id);
        Assert.AreEqual(@event.Subject, newEvent.Subject);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate this. what could be best way of mocking these scenarios according to you

Comment: IMO there is nothing to test. You have literally two lines of code in your `CreateAsync` method: Convert `EventType` to `Event`, and execute framework method. You shouldn't unit test framework methods, so you mock it. You are left with one line of code which is basically executing a constructor. If you are using `IApiClient` somewhere else, I would just unit test that and mock whole `CreateAsync` method itself.